# Scala Long - Object?

Tags: scala, long-integer

The Scala-Lang [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Long.html) say:

> Long, a 64-bit signed integer (equivalent to Java's long primitive type) is a subtype of scala.AnyVal. Instances of Long are not represented by an object in the underlying runtime system.

Java has a `long` (primitive) and `Long` (boxed).

Does Scala have a`boxed` version of this primitive?

Comment: Scala uses `java.lang.Long` as the boxed version where necessary. Same with all other primitive types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala boxes and unboxes silently, so there is just one class.  The compiler will try to use primitive values when it can, and uses boxed values when it can't.  This happens using the Value Class mechanisms, which are classes that have specific properties that allow the compiler to take them apart when possible.

More on value classes: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html

Comment: Technically, `Long` is a special case, and not something that derives from value class rules. One would better not expect `Long` to abide by these rules.